# How to refer to calculated field from another calculated field in google sheets pivote?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a pivote table with two calculated fields. Is there any solution to refer this fields when i creating new calculated field ?

For example i have:

**CalculatedField1**

```
=SUM(arrayformula('sourceCol1'))
```

**CalculatedField2**

```
=AVERAGE(arrayformula('sourceCol2'))
```

Is there any way to multiply them like this?

```
='CalculatedField1'*'CalculatedField2'
```